# Generating unique reference ids using Hashids

Tags: mysql, node.js, hashids

In my DB, I need to have unique reference ids to orders, to show the end users.

My schema includes many accounts that can potentially have many customers, which can make many orders (occasionally at the same time - both different customers, and a single customer with many orders)

I've decided to use Hashids in order to solve this. I came up with this:

```
//create a unique salt using the account id + current timestamp:
var hashids = new Hashids(accountId + '-' + new Date().getTime(), 8,
'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')

//Then, generate a unique id for every order using:
for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++ ) {
   orders[i].ref_number = hashids.encode(i, a.date.getTime())
}
```

How random would this be?
How can I validate that?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key on your orders table? That  guarantees unique values during concurrent inserts.

Comment: I do use AUTO_INCREMENT for order ids. But i'm talking about same-length, unique id string that I can show to end users so they can reference their orders... say, on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

> same-length, unique id string that I can show to end users so they can reference their orders

How about a concatenation of the customer id and the auto-increment order id?

Suppose your table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cust_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
);
```

With this data:

```
insert into orders values (8675309, 123);
```

You can create a VIEW to produce the customer reference to the order:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cust_orders_ref AS
SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(cust_id, 4, '0'), '-', LPAD(order_id, 11, '0')) AS order_ref
FROM orders;
```

Output:

```
select * from cust_ref;
+------------------+
| order_ref        |
+------------------+
| 0123-00008675309 |
+------------------+
```

Comment: Nice effort. But I prefer to give the customer something more discrete. I rather have the customers not know the amount of customers or orders in the system.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler than you think. From the [documentation](http://hashids.org/) of Hashids:

### 1) The salt should not be random in order to avoid collisions

> There are no collisions because the method is based on integer to hex conversion. As long as you **don't change constructor arguments midway**, the generated output will stay unique to your salt.

### 2) Check how random the IDs look

> Additionally, we encourage you to pre-generate a large number of ids for testing purposes — to analyze their uniqueness, whether they look random enough for your project and what your upper integer limit is (which usually depends on your system/language).

Here you have an example of how to pre-generate a large number of ids:

```js
const salt = 'my salt'
const idsLength = 10
const hashids = new Hashids(salt, idsLength)

let idsCollector = []

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  idsCollector.push(hashids.encode(i))
}

console.log(idsCollector)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hashids@1.1.4/dist/hashids.min.js"></script>
```

**REMEMBER!** When defining the `salt` variable, it **has** to remain the same for all users and sessions, if not every user will have a different hash id making link sharing impossible. The same goes for the length!